# Splitting value in a column into all columns of a row in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table of 7 columns as follows:

```
date                         org   cus_id   prod_id   sales_qty   sales_amount   profit_amount
30-AUG-14 55 12 34 56 78 99  null   null      null     null           null        null
31-AUG-14 22 32 43 65 76 88  null   null      null     null           null        null
```

Indeed, values in the first column is concatenated by values of all columns in each row.  I would like to fix it by splitting value in the first column to all columns.  The expected output should be the following

```
date        org   cus_id   prod_id   sales_qty   sales_amount   profit_amount
 30-AUG-14   55       12        34          56             78              99  
 31-AUG-14   22       32        43          65             76              88
```

I think splitting such string value is applicable but I'm not familiar to split it and put into existing columns.  May I have your suggestions?  Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use User Defined Functions to expand a value to existing or new columns.

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION AddField(s STRUCT<tdate STRING, org INT64,cus_id INT64,prod_id INT64,sales_qty INT64,sales_amount INT64,profit_amount INT64>)
  RETURNS STRUCT<tdate STRING, org INT64,cus_id INT64,prod_id INT64,sales_qty INT64,sales_amount INT64,profit_amount INT64> LANGUAGE js AS """
var fields = s.tdate.split(' ');
  s.org=fields[1];
  s.cus_id=fields[2];
  s.prod_id=fields[3];
  s.sales_qty=fields[4];
  s.sales_amount=fields[5];
  s.profit_amount=fields[6];
  return s;
""";
with mytable as (
select 
"30-AUG-14 55 12 34 56 78 99" as tdate,  null as org,   null as cus_id,    null as prod_id , null as sales_qty ,null as  sales_amount ,null as  profit_amount
union all
select "31-AUG-14 22 32 43 65 76 88" as tdate,  null as org,   null as cus_id,    null as prod_id , null as sales_qty ,null as  sales_amount ,null as  profit_amount
)
SELECT AddField(t).*
FROM mytable AS t;
```

To pass a row value to a JavaScript function using standard SQL, define a function that takes a struct of the same row type as the table.

For example:

```
s STRUCT<tdate STRING, org INT64,cus_id INT64,prod_id INT64,sales_qty INT64,sales_amount INT64,profit_amount INT64>
```

then use the Javascript code to transform your existing value

```
 var fields = s.tdate.split(' ');
 s.org=fields[1];
```

you can add in logic, IF exists don't overwrite, or create as new colum, and later run a query like this for the entire row

```
SELECT AddField(t).*
FROM mytable AS t;
```

you can find multiple complex UDF in the [migration guide](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql#differences_in_user-defined_javascript_functions)  and [UDF docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions#supported-external-udf-data-types).

Answer (score 1):

Try below

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  SPLIT(date, ' ')[OFFSET(0)] AS date,        
  SPLIT(date, ' ')[OFFSET(1)] AS org,   
  SPLIT(date, ' ')[OFFSET(2)] AS cus_id,   
  SPLIT(date, ' ')[OFFSET(3)] AS prod_id,   
  SPLIT(date, ' ')[OFFSET(4)] AS sales_qty,   
  SPLIT(date, ' ')[OFFSET(5)] AS sales_amount,   
  SPLIT(date, ' ')[OFFSET(6)] AS profit_amount  
FROM yourTable
```

You can test it with below dummy data from your example in question

```
#standardSQL
WITH yourTable AS (
  SELECT '30-AUG-14 55 12 34 56 78 99' AS date, NULL AS org, NULL AS cus_id, NULL AS prod_id, NULL AS sales_qty, NULL AS sales_amount, NULL AS profit_amount UNION ALL
  SELECT '31-AUG-14 22 32 43 65 76 88', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
)
SELECT 
  SPLIT(date, ' ')[OFFSET(0)] AS date,        
  SPLIT(date, ' ')[OFFSET(1)] AS org,   
  SPLIT(date, ' ')[OFFSET(2)] AS cus_id,   
  SPLIT(date, ' ')[OFFSET(3)] AS prod_id,   
  SPLIT(date, ' ')[OFFSET(4)] AS sales_qty,   
  SPLIT(date, ' ')[OFFSET(5)] AS sales_amount,   
  SPLIT(date, ' ')[OFFSET(6)] AS profit_amount  
FROM yourTable
```

In case if you need to cast your fields into INT - use below

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  SPLIT(date, ' ')[OFFSET(0)] AS date,        
  CAST(SPLIT(date, ' ')[OFFSET(1)] AS INT64) AS org,   
  CAST(SPLIT(date, ' ')[OFFSET(2)] AS INT64) AS cus_id,   
  CAST(SPLIT(date, ' ')[OFFSET(3)] AS INT64) AS prod_id,   
  CAST(SPLIT(date, ' ')[OFFSET(4)] AS INT64) AS sales_qty,   
  CAST(SPLIT(date, ' ')[OFFSET(5)] AS INT64) AS sales_amount,   
  CAST(SPLIT(date, ' ')[OFFSET(6)] AS INT64) AS profit_amount  
FROM yourTable
```